# Partition of a set into K disjoint subsets with equal sum

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

Given n ( n <= 20) non-negative numbers. Is there / Can there be an algorithm with acceptable time complexity that determines whether the n numbers can be divided into K ( K <= 10)  disjoint subsets, such that each subset has equal sum?

Comment: I think I'm late here but this might help others who come here: https://www.techiedelight.com/k-partition-problem-print-all-subsets/ archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210824071902/https://www.techiedelight.com/k-partition-problem-print-all-subsets/

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve on the brute force method:

```
s = the sum of all the numbers
for i = 2 to 10
  k = s / i

  if k is an integer then
    Get all partitions of the input array with a minimum subset size of 2 elements and a maximum of n-1 elements.
    Check each partition as it's generated to see if all the subsets have the same sum.
    end if

  next i
```

The hard (and slow) part is generating the partitions. You can do this with a recursive function. It shouldn't be unreasonably slow for partitioning 20 numbers. You can optimize the partition generation by throwing out partitions with unequal subset sums early.

Comment: can you please explain the part "if k is an integer then see if you can make i subsets, each adding up to k."?  I mean,  how to find i disjoint subsets that cover all the n numbers and each have equal sum?

Comment: That's the brute force part, but since you only have to do it for a few values, it's much faster. I'll explain in the answer.

Comment: ok.. waiting for the explanation. Actually i am having difficulty in implementing the part where i have to find i disjoint subsets with equal sum.

Comment: Can you please help me with the recursive partition generating function? how do i implement it?